# CDC not picking up changes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, change-data-capture

CDC has been set up for one of our databases in our test environment but it's not capturing any of the changes. I've made sure the capture job is running. I've disabled CDCs for the database, enabled them again and added the tables back, still not working.

I'm not seeing any errors (checked the job and sys.dm_cdc_errors), any suggestions on what to check next?

This database is set up in an availability group on a SQL 2012 server.

Thanks, 
Tim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured out what the issue was.  For some reason the primary database had been joined to the availability group but the secondary was not, do not know if another DBA forgot to join it when they restored or if there was an error.  Either way, this wasn't allowing the logs to harden so CDC wasn't picking up the changes.

Did a fresh backup of the primary, restored to the secondary and joined it up and CDC started working again.

Thanks,
Tim